# Integrate twilio with amazon lex

Tags: twilio, integration, amazon-lex

Can anyone help me to integrate amazon lex with twilio. I have prepared a chat bot in lex and want to integrate it with my whatsapp using twilio. I am not able to do so. I am getting as "Configure your whatsapp sendbox's inbound URL to change this message" although i have provided the link for lex.

So can anyone explain me the whole process by considering me as a layman.

Comment: Who is this messaging coming from and where did you believe you configured it? `Configure your whatsapp sendbox's inbound URL to change this message`

Comment: Hi Alan, thanks for coming forward to help me. A per my prototype, people will send message from their whatsapp which will eceive by twilio and this message will pass to amazon lex. Amazon lez will send automated reply which wll come to twilio and then to peoples whatsapp as a reply

Answer (score 0):

You just need to enter the Callback URL generated by Amazon LEX into Twilio Sandbox for WhatsApp. (It is a bit tricky to find it in Twilio, go to programmable SMS and you will see it in the middle) Just enter the link there, the rest works like a charm ;)

[Twilio WhatsApp APi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrEYX.png)